# Android - Java&XML - Break Line with Buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

I need the best solution to separate buttons by adding break line.
I tried string \n but it's not working.
It crashes the application.

Any idea?

I'm trying to create applications with buttons to access websites faster.

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button_so" android:text="@string/stack" android:onClick="goToSo" android:lines="1"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/superuser" android:id="@+id/button_su" android:onClick="goToSu" />
```

Comment: You need to give us more details than that! Any piece of code you're currently working with, what have you tried, more details about what you're trying to achieve - give us something more to chew on, your question barely makes sense right now.

Comment: Really not clear what your're asking.

Comment: what do you mean by "separate buttons by adding break line"? do you need two buttons with a little space between them?

Comment: This is still not clear.. looked at your comment - you wrote the exact thing twice without explaining what exactly you wanted to do.

Comment: They are next to each other. I want them to be under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/topHourlyLayout"  
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"


    >

       <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/button_so" 
android:text="@string/stack" 
android:onClick="goToSo" 
android:lines="1"
android:margin_bottom="7dp"/> 



<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/superuser" 
android:id="@+id/button_su" 
android:onClick="goToSu"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still not working. They are next to each other. I want them to be under.

Comment: Can't edit...  So it creates black vertical line that sparate buttons, but still second button isn't under first button.

Comment: can you post image sample what you need. i sorry but I am not clear about your requirement.

Comment: @Oen44 I updated the code after checking the image of requirement. Please have a look. Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: You just did what I did few seconds before checking your new post. Just changed horizontal into vertical. Thanks anyway.